# How to solve "Method readfile requires 3 parameters but 0 were supplied in the @Test annotation." in selenium webdriver with java

Tags: java, xml, testng

My Java Code

```
@Test
@Parameters({"filepath","filename","sheetname"})
public class ReadFilesinExcel {
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public void readfile(String Filepath,String Filename,String Sheetname) throws IOException
{
    File file = new File(Filepath+"\\"+Filename);
    System.out.println("File is at : " +file);

    FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(file);
    Workbook wb = null;
     //Find the file extension by spliting file name in substring and getting only extension name

    String fileextentionname= Filename.substring(Filename.indexOf("."));

    if(fileextentionname.equals(".xlsx"))
    {
        wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inputstream);
    }

    else if(fileextentionname.equals(".xls"))
    {
        wb = new HSSFWorkbook(inputstream);
    }

    org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(Sheetname);
    int rowcount=sh.getLastRowNum()-sh.getFirstRowNum();
    for(int i=0; i<rowcount+1;i++){
        Row row = sh.getRow(i);
        for(int j=0;j<row.getLastCellNum();j++)
        {
            System.out.print(row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue()+"||");
        }
        System.out.println();

    }


}

}
```

My Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="1">

<test name="verify read file in excel">

<parameter name="filepath" value="F:\\Excelsheet"/>
<parameter name="filename" value="Book1.xlsx"/>
<parameter name="sheetname" value="Sheet1"/>

<classes>
<class name="ExcelReading.ReadFilesinExcel"/>
</classes>

</test>
</suite>
```

I am getting below error while executing
        org.testng.TestNGException: 
Method readfile requires 3 parameters but 0 were supplied in the @Test annotation.
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.checkParameterTypes(Parameters.java:198)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:134)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:373)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:450)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1383)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1075)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1180)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:37)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:368)
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$2.call(ThreadUtil.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Maybe you have got a typo in your method signature: `public void readfile(String Filepath,String Filename,String Sheetname)`should be `public void readfile(String filepath,String filename,String sheetname)`. Java is case-sensitive.

Comment: No it doesn't help

Comment: Which TestNG version are you using? Could you share the whole stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: @ Julien Herr code edited

Comment: I am using testNG 6.9.12 version

Answer (score 1):

If @Parameters annotation is used at the method level, it should work fine so please change the code like below

```
@Test
public class ReadFilesinExcel {

     @Parameters({"filepath","filename","sheetname"})
     public void readfile(String Filepath,String Filename,String Sheetname)     {

     }
}
```